# Purity doubts and issues

Tags: jannah, ghusl

I suffer from waswas and when I was doing ghusl, I kept on struggling to remember if I did this 3x? or did I do this right? And I feel like when I was doing wudoo in my ghusl I don’t remember if I washed my nose 2x instead of 3 so after I did ghusl and dried and wore clothes I realised I might’ve done wudoo wrong, so is it permissible for me to perform wudoo again like I would for regular salah when I’m fully clothed or do I do ghusl again? Also I forgot if I gargled and washed my nose 3x so as soon as I got out of the bath I did that straight away 3x then I dried and wore clothes and performed wudoo again, is my ghusl correct?

Comment: So is my ghusl is accepted since I did perform wudoo only a few minutes after ghusl meaning i rewashed whatever I forgot to during wudoo in ghusl?

Comment: Are sure you know how ghusl is done? Pure water 3 times on your body and you are done.Don't make things too complicated and you'll have less waswas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your wudu and ghusl are correct.

If you wash the essential/fard/faraz/foroz body parts of wudu or ghusl once, your wudu or ghusl will be correct.

Essentials of Wudu:

1. Wash your face
2. Wash your lower arms from wrists to elbows, leaving no part dry
3. Clean your head (Maseh)
4. Wash both of your feet

Essentials of ghusl:

1. To rinse the mouth with water once,
2. To sniff water into the nose and blow it out once,
3. To wash the whole body.

Washing nose and gargling 3x in wudu is sunnah, not a fard so even if you didn't wash your nose and gargled three times, your wudu was accepted. By gargling and washing your nose  once or more and washing your body, you have done the essentials of ghusl so your ghusl is accepted. And if you think you haven't performed wudu properly, you are allowed to perform wudu again since there is no verse of quran and there is no hadith which prohibits performing wudu twice.

Answer (score -1):

1. say quran and other things to keep satan away
2. keep a check list to make sure you perform it correctly
3. you can do wudu with your clothes on in the sink